# encrypting mongo password in datasource definition using springboot

Tags: mongodb, encryption, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot application which has connection to a Mongo DB. The mongo data-source configured in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my_user:my_password@mongo_host:37017/mongo_db
```

I would like to encrypt `my_password` part of the datasource.
Is there out of the box solution for that?
Thanks

Comment: You mean other than not encrypting it, but to set proper file permissions?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I mean instead of plain text "my_password" I would like to set encrypted text of the password aka "likjajasljaslkjaslkjsa"

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. Now try to understand what I mean... Set proper file permissions.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg well, file permission seems weak solution to me: 1. The operation stuff , which may modify that file, will have access to the password. 2. in case of application machine hacked, the hacker will get access to the DB just by reading the file. I'm looking for some spring magic solution here, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [jasypt-spring-boot project](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) which does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not resolving encrypted value from url, we can put it in it's own property and then reference that property in the url.

**spring.data.mongodb.password=ENC(xIZhIV7nvOv5LqHfAKnvmjhyeecOT0lO)**

**spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:${spring.data.mongodb.password}@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:12345/mydb?replicaSet=rsdb**